# Arithmetic overflow error converting to int

Tags: sql, overflow

I am getting an error 'Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int' in a SP I am working on. I pulled a query out of it that has the issue (other queries may as well).

I am not really sure what could be causing it. My only thought is on line 11 the COUNT (distinct Sub_ID  + Sub_Dep_Number. This concatenation is of two strings, but I think it may be trying to add them as they are possbily in numerical format.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

```
SELECT  Distinct   countSubs.[Number Dependents] AS [Number Dependents], 
    (AVG((YEAR(GETDATE())- Year(Individual.Sub_Dep_DOB)))) AS [Average Age], [Group_Base].Group_Base_Name, 
    Individual.State_Code, [Group_Base].BASE_GROUP_NO
        , [Plan].Group_Address, [Plan].Group_City, [Plan].Group_State, [Plan].Group_ZIP
    FROM Individual 
    INNER JOIN 
    Group_Base ON Individual.Group_Base = Group_Base.BASE_GROUP_NO
    INNER JOIN 
    [Plan] ON [Group_Base].BASE_GROUP_NO = [Plan].BASE_GROUP_NO
    INNER JOIN
    (Select Distinct Individual.Group_Base,COUNT(Distinct (Sub_ID + Sub_Dep_Number)) [Number Dependents]
     From Individual
     Where State_Code = 'OH'
     and Individual.Sub_Dep_Number <> '0'
     AND ((Individual.Sub_Cancel_Indicator = 'false' AND Individual.Sub_Dep_Effective_DT <= '5/5/2013') 
OR
(Individual.Sub_Cancel_Indicator = 'true' AND ((Sub_Dep_Cancel_DT BETWEEN '5/1/2013' AND '5/5/2013') 
AND(Sub_Dep_Effective_DT <= '5/5/2013'))))
     AND Individual.RegComp_SystemSource = 'Genelco'
     AND (Individual.Benefit_Effective_DT != Individual.Benefit_Cancel_DT)
     Group by Individual.Group_Base) as countSubs 
     ON (countSubs.Group_Base = [Group_Base].BASE_GROUP_NO)
    --WHERE   ((Individual.Sub_Cancel_Indicator = 'false' AND Individual.Benefit_Effective_DT <= '5/5/2013') 
--OR 
--(Individual.Sub_Cancel_Indicator = 'true' AND ((Benefit_Cancel_DT BETWEEN '5/1/2013' AND '5/5/2013') 
--AND(Benefit_Effective_DT <= '5/5/2013'))
WHERE   ((Individual.Sub_Cancel_Indicator = 'false' AND Individual.Sub_Dep_Effective_DT <= '5/5/2013') 
OR
(Individual.Sub_Cancel_Indicator = 'true' AND ((Sub_Dep_Cancel_DT BETWEEN '5/1/2013' AND '5/5/2013') 
AND(Sub_Dep_Effective_DT <= '5/5/2013'))
))                  
    AND (Individual.Sub_Dep_Number <> '0')
    AND (Year(Individual.Sub_Age)) >= '30'
    AND (Individual.Benefit_Effective_DT != Individual.Benefit_Cancel_DT)
    AND (Individual.State_Code = 'OH')
    AND Individual.RegComp_SystemSource = 'Genelco'
    GROUP BY [Group_Base].Group_Base_Name, [Number Dependents],
    Individual.State_Code, [Group_Base].BASE_GROUP_NO
        , [Plan].Group_Address, [Plan].Group_City, [Plan].Group_State, [Plan].Group_ZIP
```

Comment: What are your data types?  Which RDBMS?  It looks like SQL Server.  If so, you'd get that error if Individual.Sub_Cancel_Indicator is an INT rather than a BIT.

Comment: thanks jason but not Sub_Cancel_Indicator is a bit though

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the error was coming from the Inner Join of the [Plan] table, I still dont quite understand it but I changed that Innerjoin to have a nested select statement in which it pulls the address from.